# With what object should I call this jQuery method?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I've been having some troubles with setting the containment of a draggable. I think I want to recalculate the containment after the drag has started.

I previously asked [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10500784/jquery-ui-draggable-containment-rectangle-within-parent-how-to-do-it-programma) [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10498837/jquery-ui-draggable-containment-parentrectangle) questions.

I think I've found the [answer](http://jsapi.info/jqueryui/1.8.18/jQuery.ui.draggable.prototype._setContainment). This is the line of code that I want to execute:

```
o.containment = this.helper[0].parentNode;
```

The only problem is I can't figure out what is supposed to call this method, it's not the draggable item itself, I tried that.

Comment: Or another thing I'd like to do is figure out how to call _mouseStart: http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui/source/browse/trunk/ui/ui.draggable.js?r=3103

Comment: Oh wow, nice editing! It looks much less verbose, thanks.